# Can I aggregate map data as array at pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to aggregate data. It works below.

| name | id | day | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ken | 01 | 02-01 | good |
| ken | 01 | 02-02 | error |

```
spark_df

spark_df.groupBy("name", "id").\
    agg(func.collect_list(func.create_map(func.col("day"),func.col("value)))).alias("day_val"))
```

I could aggregate day_val data as **list** of map. Like this

```
[{"day1":"value1"},{"day2":"value2"},{"day3":"value3"},....]
```

But I want to save it as

```
{"day1":"value1","day2":"value2","day3":"value3"}
```

Because on dynamodb I want to use it as not list but map.
Can I convert it to array or aggregate it as map?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or [`map_from_arrays`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_arrays):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.groupBy('name', 'id').agg(
    F.map_from_arrays(
        F.collect_list('day'),
        F.collect_list('value')
    ).alias('day_val')
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+----+---+-------------------------------+
#|name|id |day_val                        |
#+----+---+-------------------------------+
#|ken |01 |[02-01 -> good, 02-02 -> error]|
#+----+---+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map_from_entries`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.groupBy('name', 'id').agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct('day', 'value')
        )
    ).alias('day_val')
)

result.show(truncate=False)
+----+---+-------------------------------+
|name|id |day_val                        |
+----+---+-------------------------------+
|ken |1  |[02-01 -> good, 02-02 -> error]|
+----+---+-------------------------------+
```